# Angular $routeProvider.html5Mode route crashes after manual refresh

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, express, angular-routing, angular-providers

After enabling `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` and `<base href="/" />` in the `index.html` routes began crashes after manual reload.

Looking up for solutions I found that `.htaccess` rules will fix this problem, but different configurations didn't help.

Maybe this is because my `index.html` is in the subdirectory `/views/index.html`

**`.htaccess`**:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L] # /views/index.html doesn't work as well
</ifModule>
```

**`route config`**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'AddTaskCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'AddTask'
        })
        .when('/chat', { //this route breaks on manual refresh  
            templateUrl: 'chat.html',
            controller: 'ChatCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'chat'
        })
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

step 1: use only $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

step 2: Change your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

When index.html is start load point your app, or see more methods https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: Although problem was not in the `.htaccess` file, your link to FAQ was very helpful. Thank you